# lwc Kebab Case child component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lwc component

> testCaseINT_OpenCases

with design attribute

> CaseName

, I'm trying to refer it in the parent component as

```
<c-test-case-i-n-t-_-open-cases -case-name="test"/>
```

Can someone suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an extra `-` in the markup. The `-` is to be placed only before a capital letter, not other symbols: `c-test-case-i-n-t_-open-cases`. I'm not entirely sure that `-case-name` is a valid identifier. While I couldn't find the documentation on valid attribute identifiers, I've never seen an example that uses a starting capital letter, which suggests that you probably shouldn't be doing this, either.

Comment: it seems that it is no longer possible to create a lwc component with an underscore. take a look at this [playgoung](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qZZzNh41m/5/edit)

Comment: @dibocor The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_folder) suggests it is still allowed, and we have components in our code base that allow it. I think it might just be a limitation of playground. That said, I personally would not use underscores in my component names or attributes, as they're relatively harder to read in my opinion.

Comment: yes, that's a limitation of playground, thanks. also avoiding the use of successive capital letters in our component names lwc can also make our lives easier

Comment: Thank you, I've have changed the attribute name to start with a small letter.

Answer (score 1):

One more example:

If the component name is `te_PT_MyComponent`

Then it must be referred as `<c-te-_-p-t-_-my-component>` or `c-te_-p-t_-my-component`. Both of these are working as expected and was able to save the parent component without any errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This contradicts @sfdcfox 's answer in which he states that the `-` is only to be used before a capital letter and not before symbols. In the documentation he linked to in the comment under his answer, the example given that has an underscore does not show a `-` before it. Can you please point to documentation and/or a working example of having/needed a `-` before an underscore?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Moonpie, I tried it again and found that `-` before the `_` is optional. So keeping it or removing it has no impact on end result. So both of these are working fine  `<c-te_-p-t_-my-component>`   `<c-te-_-p-t-_-my-component>` I could not see any issue

Answer (score 0):

Another Example-
If Child componentis :**tesT_aBc**

from parent we need to refer it as c-tes-t_a-bc(all the uppercase Characters should be prefixed with hyphen(-) followed by the character in lowercase )